# Devise, i don't receive mail :recoverable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-confirmable

hi i start to adjust my devise gem and i saw one problem

when i click in link -> "Forgot your password?"

than i put my email and click "send"

Ideally,I should receive mail with some link.. but i don't receive this mail

In console log's i saw:

```
Started POST "/users/password" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-27 10:42:30 +0300
Processing by Devise::PasswordsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"E7957iR69EDbZArYyaA8tGRmtuwr6LOM+lf7geAitZU=", "user"=>{"email"=>"...@gmail.com"}, "commit"=>"Send me reset password instructions"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = '...@gmail.com' LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."reset_password_token" = 'K8XfKY4RV2ZJKHzXShj7' LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (1.0ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "reset_password_token" = 'K8XfKY4RV2ZJKHzXShj7', "reset_password_sent_at" = '2012-08-27 07:42:30.170634', "updated_at" = '2012-08-27 07:42:30.171855' WHERE "users"."id" = 1
   (174.2ms)  commit transaction
  Rendered devise/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.erb (1.6ms)

Sent mail to ...@gmail.com (1062ms)
Date: Mon, 27 Aug 2012 10:42:31 +0300
from: from localhost:3000 <local@gmail.com>
reply-to: from localhost:3000 <local@gmail.com>
To: ...@gmail.com
Message-ID: <503b24e732409_2f9224e7fbbe307c2@demitriydn.mail>
Subject: Reset password instructions
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<p>Hello ...@gmail.com!</p>

<p>Someone has requested a link to change your password, and you can do this through the link below.</p>

<p><a href="http://localhost:3000/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=K8XfKY4RV2ZJKHzXShj7">Change my password</a></p>

<p>If you didn't request this, please ignore this email.</p>
<p>Your password won't change until you access the link above and create a new one.</p>

Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in
Completed 302 Found in 2102ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-27 10:42:32 +0300
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (6.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 21ms (Views: 19.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

i copy link => // `<a href="http` // from log - and all works

What mistake I made?

according to the logs, I received a letter... but in to "...@gmail.com" nothing arrive

Answer (score 1):

As for developing mailevents you might want to set smtp settings in your development.rb

Make sure you read this completely to fully understand mailing

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

Have fun learning

Comment: No, i have already set up 5.2 in this guid + i set up  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }.....

Comment: I want you to read this part: set the correct attributes and values to make it send. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried sending it in a production environment?  I had the same issue where it would show in the log while I was in the development environment but I wouldn't actually receive an email.  However, in the production environment it worked fine.  Sorry this is not such a helpful answer, but I am not able to leave a comment.